# Apacite, Biber and Citing

Tags: apacite

No matter how I try, I cannot get citations using apacite, biber and latex working.

Here is my preamble

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,english]{article}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\usepackage{rc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=0.5cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=white]
\tikzstyle{ref} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=0.5cm,text centered, draw=white, fill=white]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\definecolor{dred}{RGB}{160, 0, 0}
\definecolor{dgreen}{RGB}{23, 93, 0}
```

and here is the end of the document

```latex
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{endnote4} 
\end{document}
```

It worked once and now it doesn't
I really don't see what's wrong

I tried with both TeXShop and TeXmaker, tried running BibTeX beforehand.

Does anyone see what's wrong ?
NB : it worked once
NB2 : I'm using a Mac running Catalina and MacTeX

Comment: If you use `apacite` you must run BibTeX, you can not use Biber with `apacite`. The correct compilation order is LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX, where the first LaTeX run should finish without errors and ideally also without warnings that are unrelated to undefined citations.

Comment: It does indeed work. Thanks! Do i need to do that every time I compile?

Comment: @RaphaëlC Just out of curiosity, why do you revert to BibTeX and `apacite`? You could use the `biblatex-apa`-package under BibLaTeX, which would give you APA-like citations **and** the flexibility and comfort of BibLaTeX and biber.

Comment: Roughly you only need to run BibTeX when you change something citation- or bibliography-related about your document. So you do not always need to run the full LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX sequence if you just change a few words of text. But before you complete your document this should be the minimal build cycle you run to make sure everything resolves as expected.